# Subjective case or objective case

Tags: pronouns

In the following sentence

Mr. Trump referred to Mr. Modi as a “true friend”, and a “tremendously successful leader”, **who** he credited with India’s progress.

I think **whom** should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The grammatically correct answer is **whom** since Mr Modi is the *object* of the sentence.

You should use **who** when the pronoun refers to the *subject*.

You can see that by rephrasing the second part of the sentence as

> Mr Trump credited **him** with India’s progress.

Please see [Who or Whom? Easy Ways to Remember](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/grammar-usage-who-versus-whom.html).